# Recursive N-Queens : missing solutions

Tags: java, recursion, n-queens

I wrote a Java little algorithm of the N-Queens puzzle (with a c*c chessboard). You'll find the code of my recursive method bellow.

It doesn't find all the solutions.

## What does my function

The idea is to make, in the main method, a first call to my function giving it the maximum number of queens until a solution is found, the chessboard without any queen and these new-queen's coordinates : x=0,y=0.

The function will go through the chessboard. For each square, it tests if the queen(0;0) can be placed (ie. : no threat). The queen(0;0) can be placed ? Well, we do it (modifying the chessboard) and we call the function (recursive call). This recursive call is done with : "maximum number of queens - 1", the modified chessboard, and the "new-queen's y + 1" (a bit more complicated).

## Found solution with n=4 and c=4 (there are normally two solutions... !)

&&Q&

Q&&&

&&&Q

&Q&&

## Recent code of my function

```
private static void setQueen(int nb_queens, ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> chessboard, int x, int y, ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>> solutions) {
    if (nb_queens == 0) { // If there isn't any queen remaining, it means we found a solution
        drawChessboard(chessboard);
        solutions.add(chessboard);
    }

    for(int i = x; i < chessboard.size(); i++) {
        for (int z = y; z < chessboard.get(i).size(); z++) {
            if(!canBePlaced(i, z, chessboard)) {
                chessboard.get(z).set(i, true); // On peut donc placer cette reine(x;y) et on le fait
                setQueen(nb_queens-1, chessboard, i+1, 0, solutions);
                chessboard.get(z).set(i, false);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Older code

```
private static void setQueen(int nb_queens, ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> chessboard, int x, int y, ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>> solutions) {
    if (nb_queens == 0) {
        drawChessboard(chessboard); // Il n'y a plus de reine à placer => on dessine cette solution
        solutions.add(chessboard);
    }

    for(int i = x; i < chessboard.size(); i++) {
        for (int z = y; z < chessboard.get(i).size(); z++) {
            if(!isAQueenAlreadyPresent(i, z, chessboard)) {
                chessboard.get(z).set(i, true); // On peut donc placer cette reine(x;y) et on le fait
                setQueen(nb_queens-1, chessboard, i, (z+1 >= WIDTH) ? 0 : z+1, solutions);
                chessboard.get(z).set(i, false);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it find any solutions at all ? what do you get as a result ? Also, put the  `isAQueenAlreadyPresent(i, z, chessboard)`, it shouldn't be problematic, but who knows. Also, using both recursion and iteration isn't really usefull ...

Comment: I edited the OP to display the results :)

Comment: Ah yes now i see why the recursion and iteration of course. But it seems to be lacking a lot of results actually, wouldn't ther be a lot more ? like, symetric of these solutions ? Like &&Q &&& &Q& which is symmetric to your first result.

Comment: Yes a lot of solutions are missing. I don't understand why. I don't think it's because of `isQueenAlreadyPresent` however.

Comment: Could you add this function's code ?

Comment: I tinhk it's because of the `z+1` in the recursive call ! And yes i'm going to write it thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh right, that's because how you call recursively, your doing `setQueen(nb_queens-1, chessboard, i, z+1, solutions);`. The `z+1` part is the problem, it will always found solution at the right of the first queen you placed on the global board.

Edit: ah you found it before, nice.

So, the problem is that the for loop act as an `if(z>=y)` because it starts at `y`. It's alright when `i = x` (reading the first line), but not when `i > x`. So an easy fix is to put `y = ( i == x ) ? y : 0` just after the first `for` loop.

There are even cleaner solution, like using a single index to go throught the whole chessboard.

I also suggest you rename your parameter as startX and startY (instead of x and y, the you can use x and y in the loop to be more clear).

Edit2: because of the rules of the games, there will never be a queen on the same line so ou can make a recursive call like  `setQueen(nb_queens-1, chessboard, i+1, 0, solutions);` (`i+1` because you start on the next line directly). Because of this, you can even remove the `int y` parameter from the `setQueen` method and always start the `z loop` at 0.

Comment: If I write : `int new_z = (z+1 >= WIDTH) ? 0 : z+1;` and then make the recursive-call with `new_z` (and not `z`), it seems that some solutions are still missing with n=4 and c=4. I should find 2 solutions and i Have just only one. Do you know why ?

Comment: You could easily remove the problem by doing `for(int i = 0; ..` and `for (int z = 0;..` That you be pretty ugly, and have a complexity of n^3. (wrighting a better solution)

Comment: So you think I can't keep my `i,z = a_parameter` in my two `for` ?

Comment: Yes you can, but that requires the other solution i wrote in the edit.

Comment: I edited my OP (to show the new code). Could I indicate your login because you helped me ? My changes are : "i+1, 0" in the recursive call AND I deleted `y = ( i == x ) ? y : 0` .

Comment: Well I tried your code and it works for me. How you call you first setQueen ?